# How can I find the number of noninteger values in array after SVD image reconstructionMATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, decimal, svd

I am doing some homework for a class and need to find the number of noninteger values in each image reconstruction (code below).

```
A=imread('bu_gray.jpg'); 
% read image into an unsigned integer array
A=single(A)./225;
%convert to decimal and set max value to 1
imshow(A,[])
%display image, [] scales to the min and max value
S = svd(A);
logsingVals = log10(S);
plot(logsingVals)

% Compute SVD of this tiger
[U, S, V] = svd(A);

% Plot the magnitude of the singular values (log scale)
sigmas = diag(S);
figure; plot(log10(sigmas)); title('Singular Values (Log10 Scale)');
figure; plot(cumsum(sigmas) / sum(sigmas)); title('Cumulative Percent of Total Sigmas');

% Show full-rank tiger
figure; subplot(4, 2, 1), imshow(A), title('Full-Rank bu_gray');

% Compute low-rank approximations of the tiger, and show them
ranks = [20, 10, 5, 1];
for i = 1:length(ranks)

% Keep largest singular values, and nullify others.
approx_sigmas = sigmas; approx_sigmas(ranks(i):end) = 0;

% Form the singular value matrix, padded as necessary
ns = length(sigmas);
approx_S = S; approx_S(1:ns, 1:ns) = diag(approx_sigmas);

% Compute low-rank approximation by multiplying out component matrices.
approx_bugray = U * approx_S * V';

% Plot approximation
subplot(4, 2, i + 1), imshow(approx_bugray), title(sprintf('Rank %d BU_Gray', ranks(i)));

%Compute number decimal values that must be stored to produce image
end
```

Side question: how can I find the number of singular values n needed to give a representation of an image that has similar/close appearance to that of the original?

Answer (score 0):

In matlab you can check if a number is an integer like so `floor(x) == x`, this will return 1 if true and 0 if false.